# Help understanding the proof of (sequential weak) coercivity of the Dirichlet integral $I(u)=\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u(x)|^2 dx$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$, open and bounded with Lipschitz boundary

Consider the Dirichlet integral:

$$I(u)=\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u(x)|^2 dx\tag {5.3}$$

and the class of functions

$\Phi= \{ u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega) : u-g \in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega) \}$ with $g \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ given.

When proving the existence of a unique minimizer $u $ in that class of functions that satisfies the weak form of the euler Lagrange equations, the first step is to prove that I is sequentially weakly coercive. I am having trouble understanding why the proof of that part in my notes is correct.

You can see below the whole proof .

I have a couple of definitions within a corollary that is used in the proof:

[image]

So I think  the proof of coercivity should start  by considering the assumptions of the definition: Let $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ be ARBITRARY and also consider an ARBITRARY sequence $(u_k)$
sucht that $I(u)\le \alpha$. I have to prove that this arbitary sequence has a weaklyconvergent subsequence in $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$

1. I don't see where they are considering these assumptions in their proof and besides they got a weakly convergent subsequence just for a PARTICULAR sequence (a minimizing sequence), because they used that $I(u_k)$ is bounded to imply that the sequence $u_k$ is bounded. Certainly not all sequences in $W^{1,2}\Omega$ have to be minimizing sequences! Therefore it doesn't look like they are following the definition. **Can you help me clarify this?**
2. **Shouldn't the proof of coercivity end once I found the weakly convergent subsequence?** Why do they end it only after using theorem 3.33 (see highlighted sentence)to prove that $u-g \in W^{1,2}\Omega$, and that is that $u \in \Phi$? This doen't seem to have anything to do with the proof of coercivity.

---

**Whole proof **

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Quoted theorems:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you share the information of the textbook you are using?

Comment: @Akira These are just lecture notes. But this section is   based on Dacorogna's Introduction to the calculus of variations, section 3.2. I found it also in Rindler's Calculus of Variations, section 2.1. In both cases it is less detailed though and the imprecisions seem to come from them.

Comment: I feel that these notes are detailed. If you don't mind, please share these notes with me.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kindness! Actually, the quoted theorems in your question (and thus in your notes) can be found in Brezis' book on Functional Analysis. That's why I very like your notes :)

Comment: @Akira No problem! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.**
There seems to be a subtle shortcut the author used here to avoid defining too many sequences and repeating arguments.

The main proof here is the proof of the Theorem 5.5, so they're defining a minimizing sequence $(u_k)$ first.
Within that proof, they're also proving that $I:\Phi\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ is weakly coercive, and using the same sequence to do so.

However, notice that they don't use the fact that $(u_k)$ is a minimizing sequence in that "subproof". They only use that fact to show that $I(u_k)$ is bounded and therefore satisfies the hypotheses needed to prove weak coercivity, but the minimizing aspect doesn't influence the subproof itself. There's also no assumptions on what that upper bound is, so the "for any $\alpha$" part is still valid.

I can empathize with the frustration of proofs that may be a bit lax with their arguments lol, especially as an introduction to the topic. A clearer way to do it may have been to prove the weak coercivity of $I:\Phi\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ in a separate lemma, but I get that there's also a tricky sweet spot between brevity and clarity.

**2.**
Since the aim here is to show the existence of a minimizer $u$ belonging to $\Phi$, they're specifically trying the show the weak coercivity of $I$ over $\Phi$, not just $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ in general.

Comment: Thank you, I have change the picture to show you the full definitions (corollary) and proof, since I wanted to ask you, about question 2, that means that X= Phi?

Comment: However, notice that the corollary says : Let X be a Banach space. So I thought$X = \Phi$ was not possible because $\Phi$ is not even a vecctor subspace. ($0$ is not in $\Phi$ unless $g$ is in $W^{1,p}_0$ which in general is not the case)

Comment: Which also leads me to the question, if it  really is the case that $X = \Phi$ why in Step 2 are they taking the sequence and showing lower semicontinuity in the whole $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ and not in $X$ (as the corollary says)?

Comment: @some_math_guy You're right, I spoke too quickly on that point. $X$ would be $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$, so the "subproof" that $I$ is weakly coercive could indeed end before the fact that the limit is in $\Phi$. That last part is just for the proof of Theorem 5.5 to show the existence of the minimizer in $\Phi$, separate from the weak coercivity of $I$.

Comment: uhmm Now I am more confused. I had arrived to your same conclusion  after thinking the whole day about it. And I thoght indeed that X =$\Phi$ and that maybe the proof of lower semicontinuity for some reason is valid on the subspace if done over the whole space. Notice that X can also be a closed and convex subset of a banach space, as Phi is. Thet don't mentioned it in the corollary but it is in the reference book ( Dacorogna)

Comment: @some_math_guy That's fair then, that might be part of why they didn't explicitly state it as a separate lemma, so that it wouldn't clash with their original definition with a Banach, which may be a stronger hypothesis than needed but can be more practical to use. I think you could basically get rid of the sentence "This shows that $I:\Phi\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ is weakly coercive" and the proof would be the same, as all they really wanted to show was that $u$ has a limit in $\Phi$.

Comment: Well but step1 does prove that I is weakly coercive, does it not? We have found that a sequence in $\Phi$ that is bounded (becuase it is convergent) has  a weakly convergent subsequence in $\Phi$. Why do you want to erase that phrase?

Comment: It does yes, what I mean is that they don't seem to use to weak coercivity of $I$ anywhere else in the proof, and doing the steps of proving it directly got them the property they wanted anyway (that the sequence has a limit in $\Phi$). Stating the weak coercivity doesn't add anything useful that wasn't already demonstrated through the arguments they presented.